# How do I stop a function? ( jQuery, .hover() )

Tags: javascript, jquery

When you hover over the squares of the picture change one after another using the interval function. Can't solve 2 problems. 
1. The function should be started only at the square on which the point. 
2. The function should stop if the cursor has left the square.

Help me think.

```js
$('.block').hover(function(){
    setInterval(myFuncSuper2, 3000);
  });

    // Change pic on hover
    function changePic(i) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            jQuery(".hero-cat_" + i).addClass("active");
            jQuery(".hero-cat_" + i).siblings().removeClass("active")
        }, i * 1000)
    }
    function myFuncSuper2() {
        for (let i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
            changePic(i);
        }
    }
```

```css
.block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.block img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
}

.block img.active {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
  <img src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/38069/39782144-fdc6-473f-b757-b8209a2e4b31/s1200"  class="hero-cat_1">
  <img src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/225396/aea85590-65df-49b9-b959-d14cefbd9d38/s1200"  class="hero-cat_2">
  <img src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/34158/e223aed5-4ea8-4e85-bb69-88e207b6c16b/s1200"  class="hero-cat_3">
</div>
<div class="block">
  <img src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/38069/39782144-fdc6-473f-b757-b8209a2e4b31/s1200"  class="hero-cat_1">
  <img src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/225396/aea85590-65df-49b9-b959-d14cefbd9d38/s1200"  class="hero-cat_2">
  <img src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/34158/e223aed5-4ea8-4e85-bb69-88e207b6c16b/s1200"  class="hero-cat_3">
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, could you provide the entirety of your code to help with debugging?

Comment: Problem is each hover you add move timeouts

Comment: `$('.hero-category').hover(setInterval(myFuncSuper2, 3000));` <-- wrong... You are assigning the interval to hover....

Comment: Yes. yes. My fall. Class wrong. Corrected.

Comment: Use `clearInterval` to stop, see my answer below for implementation.

Answer (score 0):

-- Edit: added clearing the timeouts created in myFuncSuper2 ---

Set the function for hover off, and clear the interval

```
var interval = null;
var timeouts = [0,0,0];

$('.hero-category').hover(function () {
  interval = setInterval(myFuncSuper2, 3000)
}, function() {
  if (interval) clearInterval(interval);
  for (var i = 0; i < timeouts.length; i++) {
    if (timeouts[i] !== 0) {
      clearTimeout(timeouts[i]);
    }
  }
});

function myFuncSuper2() {
    for (let i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
      timeouts[i] = setTimeout(function() {
          jQuery(this).find(".hero-cat_" + i).addClass("active");
          jQuery(this).find(".hero-cat_" + i).siblings().removeClass("active")
      }.bind(this), i * 300)
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes ,it works. But when you reset the interval, the function stops only when it is completely over. Is it avoidable?

Comment: I have undated my answer

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve needs two things:

1. `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`

   1.2. because `mousehover` will keep on adding events when you keep hovering. you need to stop that.
2. And `this` for context of current element

   2.1 because you need to enable only selected element for hover, not entire `.block` set

```js
$('.block').mouseenter(startMyFunc);
$('.block').mouseleave(stopMyFunc);

var myInterval;

function myFuncSuper2() {
    for (let i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
      setTimeout(function() {
          jQuery(this).find(".hero-cat_" + i).addClass("active");
          jQuery(this).find(".hero-cat_" + i).siblings().removeClass("active")
      }.bind(this), i * 300)
    }
}

function startMyFunc() {
    myInterval = window.setInterval(myFuncSuper2.bind(this), 1000)
}

function stopMyFunc() {
    if (myInterval) {
        clearInterval(myInterval);
    }
}
```

```css
.block {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.block img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
}

.block img.active {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
    <img src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/38069/39782144-fdc6-473f-b757-b8209a2e4b31/s1200" class="hero-cat_1">
    <img src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/225396/aea85590-65df-49b9-b959-d14cefbd9d38/s1200" class="hero-cat_2">
    <img src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/34158/e223aed5-4ea8-4e85-bb69-88e207b6c16b/s1200" class="hero-cat_3">
</div>
<div class="block">
    <img src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/38069/39782144-fdc6-473f-b757-b8209a2e4b31/s1200" class="hero-cat_1">
    <img src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/225396/aea85590-65df-49b9-b959-d14cefbd9d38/s1200" class="hero-cat_2">
    <img src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/34158/e223aed5-4ea8-4e85-bb69-88e207b6c16b/s1200" class="hero-cat_3">
</div>
```